# sub server is not working virtualmin

Tags: virtualhost, webmin

after creating sub-server in virtualmin mysql is not working .After restarting mysql it is working for sometime and and again it stop working .And also the sub server is always pointing to its main server landing page.

any help is most appreciable .
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes after giving permition in the root user to the current user it works fine change it from default to some specific.